# Is it Good Idea to Call WCF from WebApi ? In which Situation , We need to consider this in Design Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I am developing E commerce product where I will expose eCommerce catalog data to web,mobile platform to using asp .net webapi. I need to decide what architecture design I will use

Should I design webapi and wcf both and Need to call wcf serve method from webapi controller method or Should I directly call my Business layer Services from webapi ?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary. Another option which you can try is to use .net mvc, and then you'll be able to call methods of controller in similar a similar way to calling wcf service. It depends more on factors who develops mobile part and web site, and what he knows better. If he/they know better mvc, and know how to use it, then apply mvc, if they know better how to use wcf then use wcf.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your WCF service serves a purpose only it can serve, such as a state server, I wouldn't go out of my way to create a service.